# Get text from the textarea

Tags: javascript

How do I create a function that extracts the text from the textarea and divides it into the individual words and puts all the words in an array?

```
<body>

 <textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="10" id="textarea"></textarea>
 <button id="button">Click</button>


 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is what i got :P Been stuck for a while now. Can't figure out what to do. Pleas help.

```
 var btn = document.getElementById("button");
 btn.addEventListener("click", getText);

 function getText(){

 }

</script>
```

Comment: How would you define a _"word"_? What separates _"words"_? Once you can define that, you can simply use `document.querySelector('textarea').value.split(wordDelimeter)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 80% done :-)

Now you need to get the value from the textarea, replace the spaces with this regexp `/\s+/` (this is just to replace consecutive spaces) and then split the text by ' ' (single space)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", getText);

var array;

function getText() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
  array = textarea.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').filter((e) => e.length > 0);
  
  console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" id="textarea">Hello           World</textarea>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

See? now you're getting the values into an array.

**UPDATED**: According to [@phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) the `g` modifier is necessary to avoid inconsistent with new lines at first position.

Comment: This doesn't handle punctuation and newlines very well but it's on the right track

Comment: You want to add the _global_ flag to your regex, ie `/\s+/g`. That will at least take care of the newlines

Comment: Thank you for the help! I just have a small question that I would like to add. 
What does the line below do? especially the ((e)
.filter((e) => e.length > 0);

Comment: @EirikVattøy go and read this [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it's just a function to filter those elements who meet a specific predicate :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getText(){
   var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
   var words = text.split(/\s+/);
   return words;
}
```

The `value` gets text from textarea and [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) breaks text into words using spaces.