# Where is the text in a <textarea> when it is not between the beginning and ending tags?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a situation where I have typed `Hello.` into a `<textarea>` and I can see the text sitting there in the textarea, but it does not appear between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`.

It's an extremely simple situation, but I have made a JSFiddle for it:  https://jsfiddle.net/rhedin/bhwc394e/2/  If you type `Hello.` in the textarea, and examine the element in the debugger, you will see the `Hello.` in the textarea, but the element will be shown this way:  `<textarea></textarea>`

The reason I care is that I am working through Selenium.  I send a message to the webdriver process, and the webdriver process sends a message to the instance of Firefox operating in marionette mode.  When I ask webdriver what the contents of the textarea is, it returns the innerText of the textarea.  That is an empty string.  The text, that I can see visibly on the screen, is somewhere else.

Anybody know what is going on?

Comment: Use value attribute. Look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939010/get-value-from-text-area

Comment: ...or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493301/get-text-from-the-textarea

Comment: The inspection tab in the DevTools doesn't show the content of the textarea elements. Also, [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#technical_summary) can contain plain text only, it doesn't have HTML, read `value` property/attribute of the textarea instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm giving up on this.  I've discovered the following things, but I'm not satisfied.

Yes, the inspection tab in the DevTools does show the content of the textarea elements.

I've changed my JSFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/rhedin/bhwc394e/11/ ) so that both an input and a textarea are used.  Both are given both a value -- `elt.value = 'Added as a value'` -- and an innerText -- `elt.innerText = 'Added as an inner text'` .  If you examine the element in the console, you will see that both the `value` and the `innerHTML` attributes are defined.  (It seems that the browser puts the innerText value in the innerHTML attribute.  innerHTML is a superset of innerText.)

When both `elt.value` and `elt.innerHTML` are defined, `value` is given priority.  The user is shown the data in `value`.

So I've learned enough that I can solve my problem involving Selenium.  For those who might benefit, here is the critical line from my Selenium solution.  `textareaElement.get_attribute('value')`